# Import Not Working and Pip Can't Install Anything

Tags: python

Let the code speak for itself:

```
    C:\Users\thedi>pip install random
```

Collecting random
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement random (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for random

```
    C:\Users\thedi>import random
```

'import' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: 1. You don't `pip install random`, it's part of the [standard library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html). 2. `import random` is a *Python statement*, not a shell command. You need to start the Python interpreter, *then* `import random`; you should see a different prompt, usually `>>>`, when the interpreter is running. See e.g. https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/interpreter.html

Answer (score 1):

**ERROR**:

> Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement random

**ERROR**:

> No matching distribution found for random

if the above one is your error

then follow these steps-

Press

- **ctrl+f**
- **in the following website,to search module**  [https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs)

**NOTE**-

check your python version before installing any module

After installing module copy and paste in your pip folder.

follow this path to paste your module in pip folder.

```
[C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Scripts]
```

**HOPE IT HELPS!**

Answer (score 0):

Try `pip install random2`
You can search library before installing here https://pypi.org/project/random2/

Answer (score 0):

I was searching for the import "Random", none of the answers above worked but I made more research and got this. I'd be using Random as the module here.

If you're getting:
"ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement Random (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for Random", then you should check the python database here: https://pypi.org/ and search for the module you need.

If you see the module, copy the code to install the module into your shell/terminal, in this case I was copied the code for Random module which is "pip install random-string".

Make sure you're connected to the internet, it should work.

Answer (score -1):

You first have to enter the Python console to run Python code.
Type "python" and press enter to use the console after you have installed Python.

Also, please note that `random` is a built-in module, so there's no need to install it using pip, and that also might be why pip couldn't locate that package.